# Z3: Function Expansion and Encoding in QBVF

Tags: z3

I am trying to encode formulas with functions in Z3 and I have an encoding problem. Consider the following example:

```
f(x) = x + 42
g(x1, x2) = f(x1) / f(x2)
h(x1, x2) = g(x1, x2) % g(x2, x1)
k(x1, x2, x3) = h(x1, x2) - h(x2, x3)
sat( k(y1, y2, y3) == 42 && k(y3, y2, y1) == 42 * 2 && ... )
```

I would like my encoding to be both efficient (no expression duplication) and allow Z3 to re-use lemmas about functions across subproblems. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Inline the functions for every free variable instantiation y1, y2, etc. This introduces duplication and performance is not as good as I hoped for.
2. Assert the function declarations with universal quantifiers. This works for very specific examples - from the solving times it seems that Z3 can (?) re-use results from previous queries that involve the same functions. However, solving times vary greatly and in many cases (1) turns out to be faster.
3. Use function definitions (i.e., quantifiers + the MACRO_FINDER option). If my understanding of the documentation is correct, this should *expand* the functions and thus should be close to (1). However, in terms of performance the results were a bit surprising (">" means faster):

   - For problems where (1) > (2) I get: (1) > (3) > (2)
   - For problems where (2) > (1) I get: (2) > (1) = (3)

I have also tried tweaking the MBQI option (and others) with most of the above. However, it is not clear what is the best combination. I am using Z3 4.0.

The question is: What is the "right" way to encode the problem? Note that I only have interpreted functions (I do not really need UF). Could I use this fact for a more efficient encoding and avoid function expansion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no clear answer to this question. Some techniques work better for one type of benchmarks and other techniques work better for others. For the QBVF benchmarks we've looked at so far, we found macros give us the best combination of small benchmark size and small solving times, but this may not apply in this case.

Your understanding of the documentation is correct, the macro finder will identify quantifiers that look like function definitions and replace all other calls to that function with its definition. It's possible that not all of your macros are picked up or that you are using quasi-macros which aren't detected correctly, either of which could go towards explaining why the performance is sometimes worse than your (1). How much is the difference in the case that (1) > (3)? A little overhead is to be expected, but vast variations in runtime are probably due to some macros being malformed or not being detected.

In general, the is no "right" way to encode these problems. Function expansion can not always be avoided. The trade-off is essentially between expanding eagerly (1, 3), or doing it lazily (2). It may be that there is a correlation of the type SAT (1, 3 faster) and UNSAT (2 faster), but this is also not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for a solution that would lazily expand and avoid re-expanding for different variables. In any case, I have run benchmarks where (1) is almost twice faster when compared to (3). All the functions in my benchmarks are of the form f(x1,x2,...) = .... This should be picked up by the macro finder - even if I do not specify a pattern - right?

Comment: Yes those should be picked up without patterns. Currently we don't have lazy expansion, we can only turn the macro finder on or off, and for some benchmarks one is just better than the other. Lazy expansion would be an interesting addition to the solver in the future though.